# CSS Selector when pressing tabulator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following styles (using TBootstrap):

```
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav>li[class="active"]>a, 
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav>li:hover>a,
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav>li:active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav>li[class="active"]:hover>a {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#333;
    border-bottom:4px solid #333;
}
```

They work fine when interacting with the mouse. However, when I press the tabulator and any navbar link gets focused, it stills show bootstrap default styles. Also when I close a menu and then move the mouse out the link, the same style also shows. I don't know what am I missing, because I'm targeting :hover, :focus and :active. It seems that I need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I solved it.

```
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav>li>a {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    color: #333 !important;
}
```

It was about hierarchy.